# Javascript cookies to remember input value

Tags: javascript, html, cookies, input, authentication

I need to make a website with cookies for my study, but i just can't make it work.
I have tried to look for solutions everywere but couldn't find what I need, as my teacher wants easy code what he taught me. I need to make a cookie which remembers your username so when you log in next time (don't need to recognise password) you get the message "Welcome again 'user'". It must be done with easy Javascript only!

this is my javascript file(cookies.js):

```
function setCookie(cname,cvalue,exdays)
{
var d = new Date();
d.setTime(d.getTime()+(exdays*24*60*60*1000));
var expires = "expires="+d.toGMTString();
document.cookie = cname+"="+cvalue+"; "+expires;
}

function getCookie(cname)
{
var name = cname + "=";
var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
for(var i=0; i<ca.length; i++) 
  {
  var c = ca[i].trim();
  if (c.indexOf(name)==0) return c.substring(name.length,c.length);
  }
return "";
}

function checkCookie()
{
var user = getCookie("username");
if (user!="")
  {
  alert("Welcome again " + user);
  }
else 
  {
  user = document.getElementById("username").value;
  if (user!="" && user!=null)
    {
    setCookie("username",user,30);
    }
  }
}
```

And this is my login page(inloggen.html):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Inloggen</title>
        <meta charset="iso-8859-1">
        <meta name="keywords" content="Javascript">
        <meta name="author" content="Arjan Oskam">
        <meta name="description" content="Javascript">
        <link rel="Stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
        <script type="text/javascript">
            alert("Deze webpagina maakt gebruik van cookies");
        </script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/cookies.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script>
            function checkCookie()
            {
                var user = getCookie("username");
                if (user != "")
                {
                    alert("Welcome again " + user);
                }
                else
                {
                    user = document.getElementById("username").value;
                    if (user != "" && user != null)
                    {
                        setCookie("username", user, 30);
                    }
                }
            }
        </script>
        <div id="wrapper">
            <div id="head">
                <div><img src="images/logo.gif" id="logo" alt="logo"></div><!-- #Logo -->
                <div id="banner"><img src="images/banner.jpg" alt="banner"></div>


            </div><!-- #Head -->
            <div id="menu">
                <nav>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="id-ontwikkelaar.html">ID-Ontwikkelaar</a></li>
                        <li><a href="quiz.html">Quiz</a></li>
                        <li><a href="formulier.html">Registreren</a></li>
                        <li><a href="inloggen.html">Inloggen</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
            </div><!-- Menu -->
            <div id="inhoud">
                <br>
                <br>
                <h2>Inloggen</h2>
                <div id="tekst">
                    <form class="uitlijnen" id="form" onsubmit="setCookie();
                getCookie();
                checkCookie();">
                        <br>
                        Gebruikersnaam: <input type="text" name="username" id="username" placeholder="Typ hier uw username" required><br><br>
                        Wachtwoord: <input type="password" name="wachtwoord" placeholder="Typ hier uw wachtwoord" required><br><br>
                        <input type="submit" value="inloggen" class="button">
                    </form>
                </div><!-- #Tekst -->
            </div><!-- #Inhoud -->
        </div><!-- #Wrapper -->
    </body>
</html>
```

I Hope you can help me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go, code slightly updated, you were not passing parameters to setCookie function

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Inloggen</title>
<meta charset="iso-8859-1">
<meta name="keywords" content="Javascript">
<meta name="author" content="Arjan Oskam">
<meta name="description" content="Javascript">
<link rel="Stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
<script language="javascript">
function setCookie()
{
    checkCookie();
    var cname = "username";
    var cvalue = document.getElementById("username").value;
    var exdays = 7;
    var d = new Date();
    d.setTime(d.getTime()+(exdays*24*60*60*1000));
    var expires = "expires="+d.toGMTString();
    document.cookie = cname+"="+cvalue+"; "+expires;
}

function getCookie(cname)
{
    var name = cname + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for(var i=0; i<ca.length; i++) 
      {
      var c = ca[i].trim();
      if (c.indexOf(name)==0) return c.substring(name.length,c.length);
      }
    return "";
}

function checkCookie()
{
    var user = getCookie("username");
    if (user != "")
    {
        alert("Welcome again " + user);
    }
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="head">
    <div><img src="images/logo.gif" id="logo" alt="logo"></div>
    <!-- #Logo -->
    <div id="banner"><img src="images/banner.jpg" alt="banner"></div>
  </div>
  <!-- #Head -->
  <div id="menu">
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="id-ontwikkelaar.html">ID-Ontwikkelaar</a></li>
        <li><a href="quiz.html">Quiz</a></li>
        <li><a href="formulier.html">Registreren</a></li>
        <li><a href="inloggen.html">Inloggen</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
  <!-- Menu -->
  <div id="inhoud"> <br>
    <br>
    <h2>Inloggen</h2>
    <div id="tekst">
      <form class="uitlijnen" id="form" onsubmit="setCookie();" method="post">
        <br>
        Gebruikersnaam:
        <input type="text" name="username" id="username" placeholder="Typ hier uw username" required>
        <br>
        <br>
        Wachtwoord:
        <input type="password" name="wachtwoord" placeholder="Typ hier uw wachtwoord" required>
        <br>
        <br>
        <input type="submit" value="inloggen" class="button">
      </form>
    </div>
    <!-- #Tekst -->
  </div>
  <!-- #Inhoud -->
</div>
<!-- #Wrapper -->
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Well.. Now it does check the username but now it says welcome again even when you fill in your name for the first time, Hamed. it needs to be like : i fill in name Arjan. It does nothing. and everytime i fill in Arjan after that it says welcome again. and so also for other names

Comment: Hope updated code is what you are looking for :), try after clearing cache

Comment: Well it works not totally or it is my browser setting.. When i type in Arjan first time it says nothing, Second time it says welcome back. and when i type in for example Corné it says welcome again Arjan again. and after I filled in Corné for second time it says welcome back Corné? any idea if that is solveable?

Comment: when you submit the form first time, it says nothing as cookie is empty to give alert and then it saves 'Arjan'. when you submit second time it says "welcome again Arjan" and saves 'Corné' for next time and so on..., you can play with the code to get the result as you desired.

Answer (score 1):

I think that you are setting the cookies wrong. I suggest that you try console.log(document.cookie) in function setCookie after you set the cookie, and then check in Chrome console what is being shown.

Also, you can try to write document.cookie and press enter in chrome console directly and see what you get.

Basically, what I think the error is:

```
document.cookie = cname+"="+cvalue+"; "+expires;
```

Should be

```
document.cookie = cname+'="'+cvalue+';'+expires+'"';
```

Because cookie needs to be

```
userName="test; expires...";
```